# How add a grafana data link to the paricular word in table

Tags: grafana

I want to link the dashboards for each row in the table in my  Grafana dashboard, which has a table visualisation. I tried using a data link, but it is linking to the entire table when I only wanted it for one row.

I tried using a data link, but it inserted the entire table when I only wanted it for one row.

A specific row in the table can be linked to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can link only one specific row... however, you *can* customize the link on each row (or cell) based on the values of the cells in that row.

Here's some documentation related to that: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-data-links/#data-links